# Where to put AWS credentials for Boto3 S3 instance

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I am trying to run a simple python script that goes through all of my AWS buckets and print outs the buckets name. I am trying to figure out where to put my AWS credentials for authorization. In the documentation it says to put them in a specific aws config file

> Alternatively, you can create the credential file yourself. By
>   default, its location is at ~/.aws/credentials:

When running a standalone python script, lets call it s3_test.py, where do I put the credentials ? On my local machine, do I create a file called credentials at ~/.aws/ , or can I just put my credentials in the script itself ?

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

bucket_name = 'bucketnamehere'

for bucket in s3.buckets.all():
    print(bucket.name)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run the [AWS CLI](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/) command `aws configure` in your terminal and enter your credentials, region, etc.

Also see [the AWS credentials docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/credentials.html#credentials-default) for more options.

Always keep secrets out of your source code whenever possible (it's always possible).

Comment: If you have two AWS accounts, one personal, and one professional, do you need to re-configure you .aws credentials file every time you wanted to use the other AWS account?

Comment: You can have named profiles. The AWS CLI commands take a `--profile` flag to specify which profile applies.

Comment: I agree but can you help with the case where I want to locate the .aws file on my windows pc without using the command line? I am expecting something like "C:/Users/ ...

Answer (score 0):

Follow their recommendation to put your credentials at `~/.aws/credentials`, or run `aws configure` as Taylor Wood's answer, but never put credentials in your code. It's a big security risk.

Answer (score 0):

The config file is supposed to be in the "C:/Users/Username/.aws".